# Any Guide Book - to understand - 1st Person / 2nd Person / All Knowing

Tags: resources, viewpoint

As part of my self-education in my journey to become a writer / author - I would like to understand in detail - the different pov's - with good and numerous examples.

Can you suggest a book - which I can buy and read - to learn these approaches better?

Thanks & regards..
Anil

Comment: Orson Scott Card's "Character and Viewpoint" is excellent.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I couldn't think of a book, but here is a pretty good web-page: http://www.writersworkshop.co.uk/PointsofViewinFiction.html

I'm not the most experienced of writers, of course, but from my limited understanding I would say that POVs are a rather simple concept to grasp. The hard part is choosing which one you prefer to use in your writing style or in your current story. In my opinion, I would say that the best way to become familiar with the different points of view when used in the field is to actually READ a book that uses the POV you want to understand better.

Comment: We frown on link only answers, but as the question asked for one . . .